# does "dotnet publish" ignore large files marked as "content - Copy if newer"?

Tags: .net, wpf

I upgraded my WPF project from .Net Framework 4.6.1 to .Net6. Now I'm trying to publish this project (publish to local folder) but there seems to be an issue with some resource files. The files are marked as "Content" and "Copy if newer"
[File properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWc1R.png)

[Publish profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20hNI.png)

Of the six files only four (each around 850KB) are published and the other two (each around 1700KB) are ignored.

[Files after building project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpTgG.png)

[Files after publishing project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxp7O.png)

Is there a file size limit for "Content" files or is there something else I'm missing?

I tried reducing the file size of the larger files and then they get published correctly. But with the original length, they are just missing in the output folder.